# Unable to get value from converted frozen set python 3

Tags: python, loops, set

I am self-learning Python (no prior programming experience) and I am trying this question:

> ask the user to input as many bank account numbers as they’d like, and store them within a list initially. once the user is done entering information, convert the list to a frozenset and print it out.

This is my code:

```
# create global variables
b_accounts = []
fzb_accounts = frozenset()
# Create add account function
def addAccount(account):
    b_accounts.append(account)
    print('Account number: {} has been added'.format(account))
    return b_accounts

# create covert from a list to a frozenset function
def convertFz():
    if b_accounts:
        globals()['fzb_accounts'] = frozenset(b_accounts)
        return fzb_accounts
    else:
        print('List of account does not exist!')

# create show account function    
def showAccount():
    convertFz()
    if fzb_accounts:
        #print('Here your enique entered accounts:{}'.format(fzb_accounts))
        for acc in fzb_accounts:
            print(acc)
    else:
        print('No account!')

# create main function
def main():
    done = False
    while not done:
        ans = input('Please select add/show/quit account: ').lower()
        if ans == 'add':
            account = input('Enter account number: ')
            addAccount(account)
        elif  ans =='show':
            showAccount()
        elif  ans =='quit':
            done = True
            print('Bye!')
        else:
            print('Invalid option')

main()
```

> I want to add the following account numbers:

- 1234
- 12345
- 1234

> the output should be:

- 1234
- 12345

Thank all, code updated and work as expected.

Comment: If you want `fzb_accounts` to be a global variable, you need to declare it as such.

Comment: Hi @Błotosmętek, I believe fzb_accounts is a global variable as I declared at the beginning: fzb_accounts = frozenset().

Comment: `fzb_accounts = frozenset(b_accounts)` this line creates a new local variable variable (does not modify the global variable)

Comment: No, you haven't **declared** it as global, you just initialized a variable. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Comment: @błotosmętek, thank you, updated my code and it works